# Visualforce PDF not showing styles in Community

Tags: visualforce, community, pdf

I have a visualforce page which renders PDF OK when viewing in Salesforce. However, the same page doesn't renders the styles in PDF when viewing through a Salesforce community site.  Any idea what is going wrong with the PDF generation from community site?? The page is given below:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" 
    showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
    <head>
        <style>
            .grad{
            Width:600px;
            Height:600px;
            background: #0098d5; /* Old browsers */

            }
            #tst{
            color:red;
            font-size:60pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grad">
            <span id="tst"> Hello Salesforce</span>
        </div>
    </body>
 </apex:page>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What styling doesn't it render from the community? Remember that you also have a community template involved here as well that could be in contention for styling (could depend on how this page is called and where community stylesheets are referenced).

Comment: The PDF output is is supposed to be a DIV with blue background and Text with  font size 60pt. These styles don't appear in the community PDF output.  I get a standard black text without background DIV.

Comment: I suggest you to put styling in static resources and then refer it here

Comment: My requirements include customer specific CSS styles. Static resource will result in a fixed CSS.

Comment: I'd recommend you replace the span tag with a `<p>` tag (or table) and use a text align = center if that's what you're looking to accomplish. PDFs can be very finicky and work best with tables. Also, use an @media tag because the 800px won't be valid for print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `applyHtmlTag="false"` to your page and enclose the content of your page in `html` tags.

Issue is because, when you see the page as a community user.  It adds style to your HTML: `<html style="display:none !important;">`

Just tried in my dev org and it worked:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false"
    applyHtmlTag="false" 
    showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .grad{
            Width:600px;
            Height:600px;
            background: #0098d5; /* Old browsers */

            }
            #tst{
            color:red;
            font-size:60pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grad">
            <span id="tst"> Hello Salesforce</span>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Cheers, Working with PDF is very tricky sometimes.